# How to display flash message on login with passport ldapauth

Tags: node.js, passport.js, locomotivejs

So, my app uses a login through a ldap server. Once it's authenticated, I login or create a user on my database, and then proceed with my app.

However, I'm trying to display a flash message when the user fails to login with ldap (invalid credentials or whatever), but I can't get to do it the way the documentation says.

I'm using locomotive js as framework, so I'd like to keep using this routing :

routes.js

```
this.match('/', 'pages#homepage',{ via: 'GET' });   

this.match('login', passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {
  successRedirect : '/dashboard', 
  failureRedirect : '/', 
  failureFlash : true 
})  ,{ via: 'POST' });
```

pagesController.js

```
pagesController.homepage = function() {
  this.title = 'title';
  this.render('',{messageRedirect: this.req.flash('messageRedirect')});
};
```

.ejs

```
<% if (messageRedirect.length>0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= messageRedirect %></div>
<% } %>
```

passport.js

```
passport.use(new LdapStrategy( {

server: {
    url: config.ldap.url,
    bindDn:  config.ldap.bindDn,
    bindCredentials: config.ldap.bindCredentials,
    searchBase: config.ldap.searchBase,
    searchFilter: config.ldap.searchFilter,
    searchAttributes: config.ldap.searchAttributes,
    tlsOptions: {
        ca: [
            fs.readFileSync(config.ssl.cert)
        ],
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
}

}, function(ldapUser, done){

var queryUser = {...};

    user.getByUsername(queryUser, function(err,res){

        if (err) {
          return(err,null);
        }

        // if we don't find the user, it's his first attempt to login and we have to add him in the base
        if(res.length==0){

            user.create( queryUser, function(err,res){
                if (err){
                    return (err,null);
                }
            });

            var returnUser = {...};
            return done(null,returnUser,{
            message: 'Created and logged in Successfully'
            });

        }

        else{

            var returnUser = {...};
          return done(null, returnUser, {
            message: 'Logged In Successfully'
          });
        }
    });
   }
));
```

The issue I'm having is that if the ldap login fail, the verify callback is not called so I can't display login failures through it.
The flash otherwise works, since it works on several other pages. It even works on this page (e.g. when the user tries to access a page without being connected), but just not for login failure.
I tried a lot of other stuff, but this is the only part that i'm kinda sure of.

I can introduce an '/again' route to display an error, but I'd like to have the ldap one, that should be more precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[passport-ldapauth](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth) sets the messages when LDAP authentication fails, and [Passport.js then puts the message to `req.flash`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/07bff37406241b0cf8db35986788d2dadbf93763/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L115-L119) using `error` as the key if type is not defined (which is the case with `passport-ldapauth`).

You can [customize the messages](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth/blob/df03ccfe6542a7c9c3d9a1175fcadbd79bca5680/lib/passport-ldapauth/strategy.js#L118-L128) when calling `passport.authenticate`. If using Microsoft AD, you can [customize some additional messages](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth/blob/df03ccfe6542a7c9c3d9a1175fcadbd79bca5680/lib/passport-ldapauth/strategy.js#L141-L154) as mentioned in the [readme](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth/blob/0e7928ce4674e5662712b61fa49553ff6b223e5b/README.md#authenticate-requests)

So, to get the failure messages this should work:

```
this.render('', {
  messageRedirect : this.req.flash('messageRedirect'),
  messageLdapError : this.req.flash('error')
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw the customization of messages, but I didn't know what to put in `this.req.flash()`. I couldn't find any mention of the key apart for custom callbacks, which isn't what I'm looking for, even less for `passport-ldapauth`, I tried 'failureFlash' and 'message' but not 'error' as key. Now this is exactly what I needed, as I can do an error message depending on how it failed.